# Angular2 routing is not working on Production IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, angular2-routing

We have developed an Angular2 App.

we have followed [Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907463/after-hosting-angular2-app-on-iis-direct-url-is-not-working) to solve the problem of routing.

Things are working fine on Local IIS server.

The problem is on production IIS server,it simply shows loading... and no error in console.

My project structure is as below:

- app

  - components
  - services
  - app-routing.module.ts
  - app.component.ts
  - app.module.ts
  - main.ts
- index.html
- package.json
- systemjs.config.js
- tsconfig.json

Any help would be highly appreciable!!

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: Have you checked browser's console to see if there are any errors logged?

Comment: @PankajKapare I cannot see any errors in console. It seems the angular 2 routing is not working.

Comment: Check in chrome developer tools. I am sure you will find some error logged there.

Comment: I checked thoroughly but I cannot see any errors in console.
While debugging, I found that main.ts was not getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after getting help from our network team.

The problem was our company firewall. It was blocking the angular2 related code.

Our network team made changes in firewall settings to unblock it.

Thanks!