# How to publish asp.net angularjs2 project to iis server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I created angularjs 2 project with mvc in visual studio.It was working fine.But when i publish code to wwwroot folder and browse from iis it is showing error System is not defined(…).How to fix
[image: See Image Here]

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform URL rewriting.Please follow below link:

[Url rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907463/after-hosting-angular2-app-on-iis-direct-url-is-not-working)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: after hosting to iis version 10 my project is showing 'System is not defined(…)' error not even a single html page is loading

Comment: @bhargav have you implemented the steps mentioned in the link??